# How to stop Force move Layout up, when keyboard is shown in FRAGMENT

Tags: java, android, xml

I don't want to move layout up in fragment.
I have attach activity screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AndroidManifest.xml

Add  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  in your Manifest activity tag

```
<activity
            android:name="ACTIVITY NAME"
            android:exported="false" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: This is for activity but i want to do it for fragment.

Comment: getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);   try this one

Comment: Already tried but not working.

Comment: @Hardikkotadiya YOu can't control it on anything but the activity level.  Whatever you choose for that activity is what you get.

Comment: @gabe-sechan <activity
            android:name=".Activities"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

I have initialize activity like this in menifest file. so, if it is right or wrong?